# How can I customize my <input type=button>?

Tags: html, css

I’m trying to use CSS to make all my buttons this style:

```
button {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
 }
```

But now, I have a different type of button where it is `<input type=“button>`. I tried changing the CSS to make it include buttons AND inputs like this:

```
button, input {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

The problem with that, it makes ALL inputs, like text fields green. So is there any way that I can make my inputs, ONLY ones that have the button type be styled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
button, input
```

to

```
button, input[type="button"]
```

This uses CSS' [attribute selector syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors). Or give your inputs of type button a common CSS class. Ex `<input type="button" class="myButton">` and then change your selector to:

```
button, .myButton {...
```

Comment: I knew there was a way. I just couldn't find it fast enough.

Comment: That worked. Thank you very much! Will accept answer once I can.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a class to whatever elements you want styled in that way, and target the class instead of button. [CSS Classes](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_class.asp)